# shr/filling: don't split inline latex in html

Tags: latex, html, shr, filling

my package mastodon.el uses `shr-render-region` to render posts, which fills text at `shr-width`.

if the post contains inline latex, `shr`'s filling will split up the latex so that it will not be possible to render it in emacs subsequently.

is it possible to prevent `shr` from splitting inside a latex block?

inline latex blocks are surrounded by `\(...\)` or `\[...\]` characters in the html.

i tried adding a custom predicate function to `fill-nobreak-predicate`, with regexes checking if point is in-between `\` and `[` or `(` characters, or inside a `\(...\)` or `\[...\]` block, as i understood `shr` to defer to `fill.el`'s checks, but this doesn't seem to work. is that the correct way to go about this?

it looks like the most common or perhaps even only case where the latex breaks is when filling breaks a line between a `\` and `(` or `[`.

EDIT:

from further debugging, it appears that in `shr-find-fill-point`, the line `(shr-char-kinsoku-eol-p (following-char))`, returns `t` when called when point is between the `\` and `[` or `(` of a latex block, allowing the linebreak to occur at that point. it ought to return nil, like all the other tests in that function, so that point is moved backwards by one character, and then split should be permitted, with point after a space and before a `\(` or `\[`.

so it looks like my fil-nobreak regex is being ignored.

can the kinsoku rules be avoided or ignored somehow?